# What is the problem in my solution $\mathbb{P}[ \{ n,n+1\} ] = C\cdot{11}\cdot{10}^{-n-1}$ find $C$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, solution-verification

The answer I got is inccorect and I dont know why

given $\Omega=\mathbb{N}=\{0,1,2,...\}$ with the probability : $$\mathbb{P}[ \{ n,n+1\} ] = C\cdot{11}\cdot{10}^{-n-1}$$
I am asked to find $C$

**my attempt**

$$P({\Omega})=1=\large\Sigma_{n=0}^{n=\infty}C\cdot\frac{11}{10^{n+1}} $$
$$C\frac{11}{10} \large\Sigma_{n=0}^{n=\infty}\frac{1}{10^{n}}$$
$$C\frac{11}{10} \cdot\frac{1}{\frac{9}{10}}=1$$
$$C=\frac{9}{11}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a problem with the index $n$, in fact $\Omega=\cup_{n=0}^{+\infty}\{2n,2n+1\}$, so
$$1=P(\Omega)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}C\frac{11}{10^{2n+1}}=C\frac{11}{10}\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{100^n}=C\frac{11}{10}\frac{100}{99}=C\frac{10}{9}\Rightarrow C=\frac{9}{10}$$